# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'file_path' как исправить?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def otvet_na_photo(message: types.Message):
    image_id = message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id
    file_path = bot.get_file(image_id).file_path
    image_url = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{0}/{1}".format(bot, file_path)

    if not os.path.exists('temp'):
        os.makedirs('temp')

    image_name = "{0}.jpg".format(image_id)
    print(image_name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, "{0}/{1}".format('temp', image_name))
    # Replace this with the path to your image
    image = Image.open('temp/' + image_name)
    # resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
    # resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
    size = (224, 224)
    image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # turn the image into a numpy array
    image_array = np.asarray(image)
    # Normalize the image
    normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
    # Load the image into the array
    data[0] = normalized_image_array

    # run the inference
    prediction = model.predict(data)
    max_prediction = list(prediction[0]).index(max(prediction[0]))
    list_withpet = ['собака','кошка','хомяк','крыса','паук','курица','овца']

    print(max_prediction)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, list_withpet[max_prediction])
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]). Иначе сложно понять в какой строке была ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делай так

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def otvet_na_photo(message: types.Message):
    image_id = message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id
    file_path = (await bot.get_file(image_id)).file_path
    ...
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!